# Windows Boot Loader Calls Old GRUB Version

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning

I have two hard drives and two GRUB versions. Windows still relies on the old version that I want to remove. How can I make Windows Boot Manager talk only to my new GRUB version.

I started off with triple boot of Win7, XP, and Ubuntu 10.04. I have GRUB version 1.98 on the sdb drive. In order to boot into Windows, I select Windows 7 from the list and it takes me to the Windows 7 (Loader) /dev/sdb1 screen where I can select either Win7 or XP. All this works fine.

Then I decided to load Ubuntu 14.04 on another hard drive. This drive is seen by the system as sda. After loading my old Ubuntu 10.04 and running update-grub, I can see my new Ubuntu 14.04 from the GRUB 1.98 menu- no problem here.

The problem comes up when I boot directly into my sda drive. Here I see the GRUB 2.02 menu that comes with Ubuntu 14.04. When I pick Win7 from the list it takes me (properly) to the Windows Boot Manager, but then it goes back to my original GRUB 1.98 menu. The idea here is that I want to remove the Ubuntu 10.04 (with GRUB 1.98) partition and leave Win7 and XP on one drive, and keep Ubuntu 14.04 on the other drive. But if Windows is dependent on my old GRUB install, I am afraid I will not have access to Windows.

```
Disk /dev/sda: 20 GB, 

   Device  Boot     Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1        2310    18553856   83  Linux
/dev/sda2            2311        2434      994305    5  Extended
/dev/sda5            2311        2434      994304   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 250 GB,

   Device  Boot     Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *           1        6133    49263291    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sdb2            6134        7977    14811930    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sdb3            7978       12748    38323057+   5  Extended
/dev/sdb4           12749       30402   141797376    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sdb5            7979       12499    36314932+  83  Linux
/dev/sdb6           12500       12748     2000061   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

So my new GRUB 2.02 and Ubuntu 14.04 are on the 20GB drive labeled sda, sdb1 has XP, sdb2 has Win7, sdb3 is an extended partition which contains sdb5 and sdb6 which have my Ubuntu 10.04. The sdb4 partition is just common storage space.

The commands:
    sudo dd if=/dev/sda bs=512 count=1 | hexdump -C
    sudo dd if=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=1 | hexdump -C

show that there is a GRUB version in the MBR of each drive.

I would like to know how to set up my windows boot manager so it only talks to the GRUB on my sda drive and not to the GRUB on the sdb drive (GRUB 1.98). When I am done I would like the following configuration:

- sda: Ubuntu 14.04 with GRUB 2.02
- sdb: Win7 and XP with no GRUB at all

Comment: Normally Windows does not chain load grub; it goes only the other way around.  If you configured it to do so somehow then changing it would have to be done in the same way I would imagine, but configuring the windows boot loader is off topic here.

Comment: I am sorry I used the wrong terminology. Everything on my computer was done by my Ubuntu install. I just want to get rid on the GRUB version on my sdb partition and still have the ability to boot windows.

Comment: I don't understand then.  You should have a grub menu where you can choose ubuntu and it loads, or choose windows and it loads.